# Convert a visual studio python project to one executable file

Tags: python, exe

I have finished my python project and now want to transfer the project into one file, so a user can just double click it and doesn't have to compile it first.
Therefore, I wanted to know if this is possible with python.

I 've read that you can convert a single python script into an executable file using pyinstaller. But in my case I have many files in different folders and I want them to be include in the executable file because otherwise the programm doesnt work.

I also tried this via the auto-pyto-exe converter (https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe) but I didnt got the results I wanted.

Therefore, my question is, how can I convert my visual studio python-project with many different files and folders into one executable file, so a user can just double click the file to start it?

**Edit**

In the other folder are  also .py files like some FileImport.py or View.py. I separated these files that the whole project looks cleaner.

The Folder structure looks as follows:

-Views 
---MainView
---UpdateView
---AnotherView
-Controllers
---MainViewController
---UpdateViewController
-Model
---MainModel

Comment: Can you elaborate what is in all those files and folders that need to be part of the app? pyinstaller can generally work with that stuff if you set it up correctly.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: @eddyizm do you have any idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: so this is a webapp? what framework are you using?

Comment: @eddyizm this is a local App with a tabbed pane bar (The bar is called tabbed pane in Java). Therefore I have several views. I'm using the MVC-design pattern. The only framework I'm using is tkinter... If you can count that as a framework

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I have compiled python scripts with more than one script, where I import the other file in one script. What errors are you getting? I think if files are recognized and imported then it should be ok. There's some documentation on explicitly calling modules.

Comment: @eddyizm I think I found the solution. I didn't quite understand pyinstaller but as it appears it can convert a single file with its dependecies into one executable which other systems without python can open.

Comment: That's good news. Let's make sure you post your solution as the answer to this below so others can find it. I'm sure you won't be the last person hitting this issue and I unfortunately am dealing with windows for the foreseeable future :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. As it appears the pyinstaller can find all dependencies when you compile your script via pyinstaller myscript.py. PyInstaller creates three different folders where all necessary files are located. In the dist folder one executable is located which can be used from computers without python installed.
I hope this helps somebody who has the same problem.